# resize Div as iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on a responsive design that includes iFrames to load Wordpress blogs. The page loads flawlessly on all browsers but native iOS Safari, but they do not load at all in Safari. Co-workers with iPhones suggest they load but don't scroll, which I understand is a simple meta change, but my testbed device (an iPod touch) won't load them even after a firmware update to iOS6 (and I therefore have to design as though iFrames do not load at all). Among the best alternative suggestions I read was to load content into a div.

The content loads into a div nicely. The challenge now is that the divs won't resize, and resizing dynamically is a requirement of the page (the page has a jQuery slideUp header, and content adjusts as it slides). So the iFrame resizes but does not load in iOS, and the div loads but won't resize in any browser. Here is the thoroughly hacked code:

HTML

```
<div id="iFrame1"></div>
```

CSS

```
#iFrame1 {
 position:absolute; /* because I am trying everything */
 display:block; /* Yes, divs are block inherently, this is hacked code */
 float: left; /* there are two iframe divs */
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 1px; 
 width: 45%;
```

}

JavaScript

```
function resizeIFrames(){
document.getElementById('iFrame1').style.height = document.getElementById("content").clientHeight - 150 + "px";
document.getElementById('iFrame1').style.minHeight = document.getElementById("content").clientHeight - 150 + "px";}
```

I am open to all recommendations that are cross-browser compliant. I will use iFrames, divs, tables, whatever. Guide me and I will listen.

Comment: would be awesome to have some fiddle...

Comment: have you considered CSS Media Queries?

Comment: Why not just use java popout